# Vue auto select checkbox according to another array

Tags: json, vue.js, checkbox

So i have 2 different api request in my vue application. One of them is bringing the all questions.

> [ { "id": 20, "question": "Cigarette" }, { "id": 2, "question":
> "Alcohol" }, { "id": 3, "question": "Diabetes" }]

In second request is returning what client has checked from the form about these questions.

> { "cigarette": "yes", "alcohol": "yes", "mobile": "+44111111111"}

and so on...

In my form.js file i want to see the checkbox has checked if client has selected that checkbox. In for loop i have this

```
<li v-for="(ask, askey) in patientQuestions" :key="askey">
    <b-form-checkbox v-model="ask.value">{{ ask.question }}</b-form-checkbox>
</li>
```

How can i auto select this checkboxes. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you will not get an answer because no one is going to write code for you

Comment: at least an idea will be really nice. I am kinda stuck

Comment: difficult to answer for me, it's not well asked

Comment: please share your whole code to make it easier for us to provide the answer

Comment: My whole code is over 1000 line. I thought I explained enough but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more difficult than it needs to be because you need something to relate the answer to the question. You'd want something that's the same in both cases and you don't really have that right now. The answers key and question text *almost* match, but one is lowercase and the other one is not. It would be easier/more reliable if you could for example get the question ID in the answer object.

Given your current data structure, you could do this:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(pq, index) in patientQuestions" :key="pq.id">
      <b-form-checkbox value="yes" v-model="answers[pq.question.toLowerCase()]">{{ pq.question }}</b-form-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    patientQuestions: [{
        "id": 20,
        "question": "Cigarette"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Alcohol"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Diabetes"
      }
    ],
    answers: {
      "cigarette": "yes",
      "alcohol": "yes",
      "mobile": "+44111111111"
    }
  }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/1bheo648/

Comment: okay i got the point i will update the form input names according the other names and i will try your code. Thanks